# IndexError: list index out of range when manually creating a spark data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create a spark dataframe of (one column `DT` and one row with date of `2020-1-1`) manually.

```
DT
=======
2020-01-01
```

However, it got the error of `list index out of range`?

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .master(f'spark://{IP}:7077')\
        .config('spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version', '2')\
        .appName('g data')\
        .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic')

dates = spark.createDataFrame([(pd.to_datetime('2020-1-1'))], ['DT'])
```

Traceback:

```
 in brand_tagging_since_until(spark, since, until)
---> 81         dates = spark.createDataFrame([(pd.to_datetime('2020-1-1'))], ['DT'])

/usr/local/bin/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    746             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    747         else:
--> 748             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    749         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    750         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

/usr/local/bin/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    419             if isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
    420                 for i, name in enumerate(schema):
--> 421                     struct.fields[i].name = name
    422                     struct.names[i] = name
    423             schema = struct
```

Comment: What are the row and columns you're trying to create? Is `DT` the column name in a single column dataframe, or a value in the row?

Comment: DT is the column name with type of datetime, it should have a single row of `2020-01-01`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add an answer. There are two seperate wrinkles here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here, though one is not surfaced in your example. Your immediate issue is that the constructor is expecting a `,` after the value in the tuple. But, just adding this naively will silently fail, as the constructor doesn't know what to do with a pandas Timestamp object.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
​
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("timestamp").getOrCreate()
​
val = pd.to_datetime('2020-1-1')
spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[(val,)],
    schema=["DT"]
).show()
+---+
| DT|
+---+
| []|
+---+
```

You'll want to convert this to a raw Python datetime object beforehand if you want to use the constructor like this.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
​
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("timestamp").getOrCreate()

val = pd.to_datetime('2020-1-1')
spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[(val.to_pydatetime(),)],
    schema=["DT"]
).show()
+-------------------+
|                 DT|
+-------------------+
|2020-01-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

With that said, it's not clear to me where this is most cleanly documented. If you're curious, you can see this requirement in the Spark [codebase](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3959f0d9879fa7fa9e8f2e8ed8c8b12003d21788/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L1202-L1203), or in the source code [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html).

If you pass a pandas DataFrame to the constructor, this is handled under the hood.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"DT": [val]})
spark.createDataFrame(
    data=df
).show()
+-------------------+
|                 DT|
+-------------------+
|2020-01-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: I read the code and found eventually it will do `dates = dates.toPandas()['DT'].values`. Is it the final `dates` same as the `df` in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

A more straightforward way to create the dataframe without relying on pandas:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dates = spark.createDataFrame([['2020-01-01']], ['DT']) \
             .withColumn('DT', F.col('DT').cast('timestamp'))

dates.show()
+-------------------+
|                 DT|
+-------------------+
|2020-01-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```